# Remove Commas in CSV without adding extra columns

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I have this script intended to remove "extra commas" within a string in a CSV.

```bash
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Removing commas from FILE CSV file...
type nul > "H:\CONVERT_CSV.csv"
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('type "H:\FILE.csv"') do (
    set row=%%i
    set row=!row:"=!
    echo.!row!>> "H:\CONVERT_CSV.csv"
)
```

But my script, instead of removing the comma, it adds an extra field within that record.

I know the problem sits in the `set row!row"=!` line, but I can not figure out what.

Please help

Example

From this:

```
Column A,Column B
Now,All,2
Then,After
```

To this:

```
Column A,Column B
Now,All 2
Then,After
```

EDIT: EXTRA INFO:
the csv has:

```
123 ,the time, "Gone, For good", 2023
```

Then it should become:

```
123 ,the time, "Gone For good", 2023
```

Comment: `set row=!row:"=!` is designed to remove quotes `"` from `row`. You'd need to add another line `set row=!row:,=!` to remove the commas.

Comment: As your question implies both, you should clarify whether you are supposed to be removing a comma character, or replacing it with a single space character. You will also need to explain exactly how the script is supposed to know which commas are field separators, and which are field string characters.

Comment: Thank you for your Clarification.
As at this moment I would have to remove the commas that are in the string between the ".

for example the csv has ***123 ,the time, "Gone, For good", 2023****

Then it should become ***123 ,the time, "Gone  For good", 2023****

Comment: Why you didn't put this _crucial_ information in the question itself? Nor an example of a "string between quotes with a comma"... **`:(`**

Comment: Sorry Aacini.  I have added the info to the totality

Comment: Do you know the number of columns beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

For each line, replace spaces with a unique character ('#' here) (because commas and spaces both are used as delimiters).
Then disassemble this line into tokens (columns) (there are no spaces anymore, so it delimits at commas only), remove any commas from the token and reassemble the line, while reverting the special char back to spaces:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
type file.csv
echo ---------
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.csv) do (
  set "line=%%a"
  set "line=!line: =#!"
  set "newline="
  for %%b in (!line!) do (
    set "colum=%%b"
    set "colum=!colum:#= !"
    if not defined newline (set "newline=!colum:,=!") else (set "newline=!newline!,!colum:,=!")
  )
  echo !newline!
))>"CONVERT_CSV.csv"
type "CONVERT_CSV.csv"
```

Output:

```
Column A,Column B
Now,All 2
Then,After
123 ,the time, "Gone, For good", 2023
---------
Column A,Column B
Now,All 2
Then,After
123 ,the time, "Gone For good", 2023
```

this might need some adaptions if your data contains certain special characters not shown in your example.

The more obvious approach would be a `for /f "tokens=1-x delims=,"` loop, but then you need the number of columns and all lines have to have the same number. I didn't receive an answer to my questions, so I used a different approach (no need to know and lines can even have a different number of columns)